# Get Item is returning this error "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold."

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, power-automate

I have this GetItems from SharePoint:-

[image: johnjohn123_1-1688129507335.png]

but this is returning this error:

**The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold.**

now if I remove the Order BY or I orderby a single field the action will only return "467" items >> so why i can not Order BY multiple fields? and is there any workarounds to get this working the filter and the order by?

For example this action with single OrderBy will work fine:-

[image: johnjohn123_2-1688129933616.png]

and the Compose it will return only 467 items..

Comment: Have you added a compound column index on both “Design Period” and “FY”, in that order?

Comment: @GregW yes they are indexed

Comment: Specifically together, not as two separate indexes?

Comment: @GregW no 2 separate indexed

Comment: They need to be in the one index, in the same order you’re filtering by in the where clause.   Only one index will be used per query, same as with SQL Server.

Comment: @GregW ok will try this thanks for the help